# Google Omnibox Searches getting crashed when Chrome Extension is Installed (Happening Intermittently to only few Users)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webrequest

I have a Chrome Extension, Requestly which allows you manipulate HTTP Requests. 3-4 Users have faced an issue where Searching in Omnibox is Crashing the Google Search Results Page while rest of the pages work fine.

Please have a look at this [Gif](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/e3d935a44694804d705e5035af1103d6231e4dab/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f344e7a587650622e676966) for more understanding.

Issue seems to be resolved by couple of ways:

1. Export Rules, Delete Rules, Restart Browser, Import Rules
2. Simply Restart Browser
3. Clearing Cache

This issue is reproducible on Ubuntu 14, Windows 8.1 Chrome 42. I have Ubuntu 12.10 Chrome 42 and I never saw this issue.

Here is the [background.js code on Github](https://github.com/blunderboy/requestly/blob/2046086b0469caee3cc91703f779e98c93dae829/src/background/background.js). I am just wondering the cause of issue. I have used the following in my code

1. chrome.storage.sync
2. chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest (Blocking Option)
3. chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders (Blocking Option)

I have observed another Chrome Extension, Scritsafe is facing the same issue. Details mentioned in this [thread](https://code.google.com/p/scriptno/issues/detail?id=291) but the users are still not able to completely get rid of this bug.

One of the kind and helpful user [gave me this information](https://github.com/blunderboy/requestly/issues/41#issuecomment-102465642) by enable logging while launching Chrome but I am not sure if these logs are helpful. These are the logs:

```
[13753:13788:0515/203052:WARNING:spdy_session.cc(2373)] Received HEADERS for invalid stream 7
[13753:13788:0515/203052:WARNING:spdy_session.cc(2373)] Received HEADERS for invalid stream 11
[133,3746404608:17:30:52.858104] Native Client module will be loaded at base address 0x0000702d00000000
[13753:13788:0515/203058:WARNING:spdy_session.cc(2373)] Received HEADERS for invalid stream 17
[13753:13788:0515/203210:WARNING:spdy_session.cc(2373)] Received HEADERS for invalid stream 55
[13791:13791:0515/173212:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(37)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: 0/1
```

Main problem is I am not able to manifest this on my machine. If I am able to manifest this, I would certainly try some random things and figure this out.

I have done enough Google Research. Now How should I approach to fix this issue ?

**Edit:**
Clone of this question is also available in [Google Chrome Extension Forum](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/y25kJWgM_9M). Simon Knott has also faced the same problem/bug.

He mentioned to avoid blocking all requests (Avoid especially XHR).

Comment: Could you keep `chrome://net-internals` open and export its events when the tab crashes? Make sure that you occasionally clear the logs to avoid having a log of like 1 hour of useless information.

Comment: @RobW What are these events and how could they be useful ?

Comment: If the crash is caused by the use of webRequest, then you'd see what headers were modified by the extension (before the tab crashed). Private details such as cookies are stripped by default, in case you're wonderinng.

Comment: @RobW This issue still happens even if no header is modified by Chrome Extension. If you look at the gif mentioned in post, this issue happens even if there is no extension installed except Requestly. Moreover, there was no rule active as shown in gif which states there was no header modification done by this Chrome Extension...There is some interesting comment here on Google Forum Post https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/y25kJWgM_9M

Comment: Your extension *does* unconditionally modify the request / response headers: [`return { responseHeaders: responseHeaders };`](https://github.com/blunderboy/requestly/blob/2046086b0469caee3cc91703f779e98c93dae829/src/background/background.js#L203). I have worked on various parts of Chrome's webRequest implementation, so if you provide more context, I might be able to help you further.

Comment: @RobW Nice catch..Yes you are right I should modify request/response headers only when there is actually some modification in header..I will do that change instantly..Do you think this can be a probable issue ? But why then it is only happening to a few users not everybody.

Comment: Doing so will probably reduce the odds of triggering the bug. But it'd be nice if you provide debugging information so that the real cause of the bug can be found, and resolved so that every Chrome extension developer (and user) can benefit. As for why it happens to some users only: I don't know, that's why I need those log files ;)

Comment: @RobW I'd definitely provide you the event log. Actually I am not able to reproduce this bug either. I would install Ubuntu 14.10 in VM with Chrome 42 to see I can manifest this. As soon as I get these details, those would be shared right in these posts :)

Comment: @RobW You correctly pointed the mistake. This issue is fixed now. Can you please post that as an answer so that I can accept.

Comment: My suggestion is only a work-around, and does not solve the root cause. Have you asked the user who could reproduce the issue to add Google (e.g. `www.google.com`, or `www.google.[their local tld]`) to your list, and see whether the crashes return?

Comment: @RobW Unfortunately (or fortunately) none of the users came back to me ever since I made that fix. Bug should be available with [this tag](https://github.com/blunderboy/requestly/releases/tag/v3.3.0). Moreover this bug was reproducible only on Windows Chrome v41 or so.